# ACER Aspire V5-131-2840 brighness control with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, graphics

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on an ACER Aspire V5-131-2840 netbook. Everything except the screen brightness controls is working.

Under System Settings>System>Details it reports Graphics: Unknown.

Any help to make graphics card and brightness controls work correctly is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

So this won't totally resolve your problems, I think the problem is your system that cannot use the fn + brightness key, that but you can install this program that will use the shortcut CTRL+F11 and CTRL+F12 for the brighness

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:indicator-brightness/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-brightness
```

Answer (score 0):

I note also that the ACER ASPIRE V5-131-2887 comes with Linux Linpus pre-installed, not sure if the Intel graphics chip is the same though. But curious to know if the Linpus  distro would be a better option that Ubuntu and if all keyboard features like brightness controls work?

Answer (score 0):

After some hunting on the web I found the following solution that allows the Fn+> and Fn+< keys to work to adjust the brightness with 10 steps. However, the popup (which previously had 5 steps) and system settings app for brightness control do not work now.

GRUB needs to be modified to get the keypad brightness buttons to work:
Code:

---

sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

---

Change the line
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
Then:
Code:

---

sudo update-grub

---

Then restart.

Thanks to the following:

http://ubuntuaddict.com/solved-installing-12-04-3-on-a-acer-aspire-v5-131-2629.html